# ReportViewer VS 2010: Display only 2 rows

Tags: reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I am using ReportViewer in VS 2010.

I have a table that displays the following data:

11(2009)
13(2009)
16(2010)
21(2009)
3(2010)
4(2009)
6(2009)
8(2009)
9(2010)

However it should display the following:

11 (2009)   16 (2010)   3 (2010)    6 (2009)    9 (2010)
13 (2009)   21 (2009)   4 (2009)    8 (2009)

How do I do this? Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this may it works

```
    System.Environment.NewLine
```

replace System.Environment.NewLine instead of \n

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry I did not understand your suggestion. Where should I put the newline? Thanks!

Comment: I added System.Environment.Newline however that does not give me the desired result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with the way you have the report set up to display to actual information.  Can you provide a little more information on the format of your report?